# Is it possible to test the CAN loopback mode without using oscilloscope?

Tags: embedded, can-bus

I am working on the CAN on LPC1857 microcontroller. This is the first time I am working on the CAN driver.
I am right now testing the loopback mode in CAN. I have successfully transmitted the message. This I know because of the values in the status register. But now I need to verify whether I have received the same message at the receiver end. Since I do not have any oscilloscope with me, I wanted to know whether it is possible to check the output at the receiver end using software. I am using LPCxpresso IDE for the coding purpose. If yes, can you please give me a brief idea about how it is done?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Pavan.

Comment: Well, does the rx interrupt happen?

Comment: Hello Martin James,

Thanks for the reply. The rx interrupt is not happening. And also I dont see the change in the status register as well. This made me think that the loopback mode is not working.

Thanks,
Pavan.